# How do you install a uncvideo driver for a Logitech C910?

Tags: driver, webcam

According to the verified peripheral http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals my Logitech C910 HD camera should work with the "uncvideo" driver.

How do I install this driver? Is it a simple as copying it to a particular directory or is there a more elaborate process?

And when it says "works with external power" what exactly do they mean by that? Does it mean I can't depend on my raspberry pi to power the web cam? How else am I going to power it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information was quite hard to find, but the `uvcvideo` module is built into the Raspberry Pi kernel. You can see for yourself in the [kernel source here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.2.27/drivers/media/video/uvc), or in your filesystem at:

```
/lib/modules/${uname -r}/kernel/drivers/media/video/uvc
```

This means that the module should work when you plug in your cam. If not then executing this should do the trick:

```
modprobe uvcvideo
```

And as ikku says, the camera will need an external power source, such as a usb hub, as the camera requires a lot of power.

Comment: I'm a little confused, what's the difference between "uncvideo" and "uvcvideo".  On the Verified Peripherals website the C910 is marked to work with "uNcvideo", not "uVcvideo".  Or was this a mistake on their part?

Comment: I'm starting to think "uNcvideo" is a mistake because even this site states that "uVcvideo" supports the Logitech C910: http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices

Comment: I think it's a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

About "works with external power":

This generally means that it has been tested with a USB hub that uses an external power supply. So the power needed for the devices connected to this USB hub is not extracted from the Raspberry Pi but from this external power supply. The Raspberry Pi can only provide around 140mA per USB port, while the USB specifications state that a device might use a maximum of 500mA (5 USB 2.0 unit loads of 100mA).

Using a externally powered USB hub will ensure that no significant power will be used from the USB port on the Raspberry Pi. (So keeping it way under the limit of 140mA) And all devices connected can still dissipate the full 500mA as specified. (if the external power supply can provide this of course)