# IWebcam recommendation for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

May I know which is the best to use on a Raspbery Pi USB slot: a LOGITECH 15MP 1080P HD WEBCAM C920, a LOGITECH HD Pro Webcam C910 or a LOGITECH Webcam C525 8MP HD? I need this info because I am not sure which one is good for a home automation system. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/streaming-h264-with-logitech-c920) is somebody using the C920 with a Raspberry Pi.

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/how-do-you-install-a-uncvideo-driver-for-a-logitech-c910) is somebody using the C910 with a Raspberry Pi.

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=13571) is somebody using the C525 with a Raspberry Pi.

General advice, do not use a USB webcam on a Raspberry Pi. Find a suitable camera that can use the dedicated camera port, it will take a huge load off the CPU. [See here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=lmK4CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA42&ots=ByAMaP8sw_&dq=raspberry%20pi%20mipi%20vs%20usb%20webcam&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q=raspberry%20pi%20mipi%20vs%20usb%20webcam&f=false).

Comment: Good answer.  Of course, if you really want 15 MP resolution and are willing to accept the processor load, then a webcam is probably your only choice.  Although USB video is supposed to be standardized at this point, do search around first to make sure there is a working linux driver because to the extent that a camera does not adhere to or extends the standard, someone has to reverse engineer a driver for it, since manufacturers rarely provide them in digestible form.

Answer (score 2):

A [Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) would be a good option, as they don't require as much power (both electrical and processing power), and they have a smaller footprint than most USB webcams.